# Proving an extension of the conjugate root theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

In our analysis class, we just proved the complex conjugate theorem - that for any polynomial with real coefficients and a root $z$, $\overline{z}$ is also a root of that polynomial. I searched online to try to find a generalization of this fact, and ended up piecing together something like the following:

> Let $L/K$ be a field extension, let $p\in K[x]$ and $z\in L$ such that $p(z)=0$. If $\sigma\colon L\rightarrow L$ is a ring homomorphism such that $\sigma$ fixes the elements of $K$, then $\sigma(z)$ is a root of $p$.

This would certainly be nice if true, but coming from an intro to analysis class I don't have the right tools to prove it and can't find a proof online. It doesn't stem easily from the (purely algebraic) proof of the complex conjugate theorem we were shown, either. How can I prove this statement?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Write the expression for $p(z)=0$ and apply $\sigma$ to both sides; use that $\sigma$ is a ring homomorphism that fixes the elements of $K$.

Comment: Ah, so it actually does generalize nicely from the algebraic proof of the conjugate root theorem! I assumed that a complicated-looking statement would necessarily take higher-level machinery - good lesson for the future. Thank you!

Comment: Morally speaking the conceptual point is that a ring homomorphism is, by definition, the sort of map that makes statements like this true.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Out of curiosity, is there a formalization of that idea? I.e. a theorem about morphisms in general categories that the above theorem "falls out" of as a (very) special case? I know that's imprecise, but I see a lot of similar nice theorems about homomorphisms and a higher-level intuition for them would be nice.

Comment: @Nico: it's built into the definition of ring homomorphisms. You could pick a different choice of morphisms and then it wouldn't be true so it's not a fact about general categories. A somewhat more general fact is that a homomorphism of algebraic structures preserves the truth of any identities between different terms constructed out of the algebraic operations, but again, this is more or less by definition.

Answer (score 2):

**Key Idea**  $\rm\:\sigma:\ w\,\mapsto\, \overline w\:$ preserves $\rm\:\color{#c00}{sums\,\ \&\,\ products},\,$ and $\rm\:\color{#0a0}{fixes\ elements}\in\color{#0a0}{  K},\:$ therefore by induction, it *preserves* polynomials $\rm\  \overline{f(w)} = f(\overline w),\ \ f(x)\in\color{#0a0}{K}\:\![x],\ $ having all $\,\color{#0a0}{{\rm coef's\in K}},\,$  since such polynomials are *compositions* of said basic operations. $ $ More explicitly
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
\rm \overline{f(w)}\:
&=&\rm\ \  \overline{a_n w^n +\,\cdots + a_1 w + a_0}\\
&=&\rm\,\ \overline{a_n w^n}\, +\,\cdots + \overline{a_1 w} + \overline a_0\quad by\ \ \ \color{#c00}{\overline{x+y}\, =\, \overline x + \overline y}\ \ \ \forall\ x,y \in L\\
&=&\rm\,\  \overline a_n\,  \overline w^n+\,\cdots + \overline a_1\overline w + \overline a_0\quad by\ \ \ \color{#c00}{\overline{x\, *\, y}\, =\, \overline x\, *\, \overline y}\ \ \forall\ x,y \in L \\
&=&\rm\,\ a_n\, \overline w^n + \,\cdots + a_1 \overline w + a_0\quad by\ \ \ \color{#0a0}{\overline a = a}\ \  \forall\ \color{#0a0}a\in \color{#0a0}{K}\\
&=&\rm\  f(\overline w)\\
\rm\!\! So\ \ 0 = f(w)\! \ \Rightarrow\ 0 = \bar 0 = \overline{f(w)}\:& =&\ \rm f(\overline w),\ \ i.e.\ \ w\ root\ of\ f\,\Rightarrow\, \overline w\ root\ of\ f\quad {\bf QED}
\end{eqnarray}\qquad$$

**Remark** $ $ It's just the obvious generalization of [the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2130492/242) of the  complex Conjugate Root Theorem (case $L/K=\Bbb C/\Bbb R)$.

More *conceptually*, see the notion of [algebraically indistinguishable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/148269/242).

Comment: Glad to see you posting again.